# Connecting ASP.NET app to SQL database issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert some data from my web app into a database table. Whenever I run the code it jumps to the exception straightforward. Even if I set breakpoints, the debugging doesn't stop in order for me to check the parameters. I even checked if the table would accept the datatype inserted from my web app by inserting the same data manually into the table and its working.

Here is my code

```
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim IP As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim Country_Code As String = TextBox4.Text
        Dim Country As String = TextBox5.Text

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=***.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=IP_Loc;User ID=********;Password=************;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IP_Info(IP, Country_Code, Country) VALUES (@IP, @Country_Code, @Country)", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", IP)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country_Code", Country_Code)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Dispose()
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Database Connection Error")
        End Try
```

I have covered the User ID and Password as it is a local server. Any suggestions on how to tackle the issue?

Here is the Error it is at `conn.open()`

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Server'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()`

Comment: at which point does the exception get raised? and what is the exception?

Comment: What's the poit to use a message box without telling at least the exception message? Change it to `MsgBox("Data error:" + ex.Message)` and post the relevant message

Comment: Your connection string is not correct - change it to include correct username and password and server instance

Comment: @codingbiz Already included, I just put asterisks

Comment: It says your username=Server, is that correct? Do you use "Server" as the username to log into your SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have declared sqlcommand two times. corrected program

```
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

            Dim IP As String = TextBox3.Text
            Dim Country_Code As String = TextBox4.Text
            Dim Country As String = TextBox5.Text             
                Try
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=***.***.***.***;Initial   Catalog=IP_Loc;User ID=********;Password=************;Integrated Security=True")
                conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IP_Info(IP, Country_Code, Country) VALUES (@IP, @Country_Code, @Country)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", IP)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country_Code", Country_Code)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Dispose()
                conn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Database Connection Error")
            End Try
```

Comment: While you are right I think that this is not the cause of the exception.

Comment: I think,error should be in sql connection string. Try to declare conn inside try block.

Comment: @MohitPandey Did it, still the same.

Comment: @HumamShbib: you have problem with connection string

Comment: @HumamShbib: check datasource name ,user...fro correct spelled names

Comment: @RavindraBagale I copied it from the source connection, its the same.

Comment: @RavindraBagale   Its an ip address

Comment: @HumamShbib: Show your connection string. I think problem lies there.

Comment: There is no issue with the code, I suggest check the db connection string. Use the credentials to directly connect with SQL server and verify before we can jump on the conclusion. Also verify the Provider information.

Comment: @HumamShbib: If you copy conn from the source connection,then i think you might forget to replace '/' with '//' and also add Integrated Security=True.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid user account on the server machine to use that connection string.
You specify `Integrated Security=True`, this means that the windows current user (`server`) that try to connect to the SqlServer located at the specifyed IP address should be a valid windows account also for that machine.

I suspect that the SqlServer doesn't recognize the user `Server` and thus you get a failed connection exception. You could try to remove the Integrated Security=True from your connection string, but this means that the User ID and Password are valid for the server machine

See docs on [Integrated Security here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When
>   true, the current Windows account credentials are used for
>   authentication. If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated
>   Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and
>   Integrated Security will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  right click the solution in solution explorer and select clean.  then try running with break points again.